# GSL ODE solver returns "ERROR: integration limits and/or step direction not consistent"

Tags: c++, ode, gsl

I'm writing a C++ code to solve the Lorentz force ODE, and I'm using the GSL library. I set an integer as the number of particles to be simulated and solved by the ODE, and print the states (x,y,z,vx,vy,vz) at each step. The initial values of position and velocity values are configured as random values from a GSL library. The code works for 1 particle, but returns "ERROR: integration limits and/or step direction not consistent" for any number of primaries > 1. I have tried different options, but haven't so far figured out what's wrong with my script. Below is the full code.
I'd really appreciate any feedback on how to overcome this. Thanks a lot in advance.

Br,
Leonardo.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_errno.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_vector.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_odeiv2.h>

using namespace std;

int lorentzODE (double t, const double s[], double f[], void *params);

int main(){

   int noPrimaries = 2;
   double q = 1.0;                           // Particle charge
   double m = 1.0;                           // Particle mass
   double B[3] = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0};            // Magnetic field
   double E[3] = {0.1, 0.0, 0.5};            // Electric field

   double x0[3];                 // Initial position
   double v0[3];                 // Initial velocity

   const gsl_rng_type * T = gsl_rng_ranlxs0;
   gsl_rng * r = gsl_rng_alloc(T);
   gsl_rng_set(r, (unsigned long) time(NULL));

   double t0 = 0.0;
   double tf = 100.0;
   double dt = 0.05;

   double system[6];                  // Initial state vector
   int status;                       // status of driver function
   double paramsB[8];
   paramsB[0] = q;
   paramsB[1] = m;
   paramsB[2] = B[0];
   paramsB[3] = B[1];
   paramsB[4] = B[2];
   paramsB[5] = E[0];
   paramsB[6] = E[1];
   paramsB[7] = E[2];

   const string &solverMethod = "RK8PD";
   const double h = 1.0e-06;
   const double epsAbs = 1.0e-08;
   const double epsRel = 1.0e-10;

   // Integrator configuration
   double t, t_next;
   gsl_odeiv2_system odeSystem;
   odeSystem.function = lorentzODE;
   odeSystem.dimension = 6;
   odeSystem.params = paramsB;

   // Algorithm option
   gsl_odeiv2_driver *drv;
   drv = gsl_odeiv2_driver_alloc_y_new(&odeSystem, gsl_odeiv2_step_rk8pd, h, epsAbs, epsRel);

   for(int i=0;i<noPrimaries;i++){

      x0[0] = gsl_rng_uniform (r);
      x0[1] = gsl_rng_uniform (r);
      x0[2] = gsl_rng_uniform (r);
      v0[0] = gsl_rng_uniform (r);
      v0[1] = gsl_rng_uniform (r);
      v0[2] = gsl_rng_uniform (r);
      system[0] = x0[0]; system[1] = x0[1]; system[2] = x0[2];
      system[3] = v0[0]; system[4] = v0[1]; system[5] = v0[2];

      for(t_next = t0+dt; t_next<tf; t_next += dt){
        
         status = gsl_odeiv2_driver_apply(drv, &t, t_next, system);
         if(status != GSL_SUCCESS){
            printf("Error: status = %d\n", status);
            break;
         }
         printf("%.5e %.5e %.5e %.5e %.5e %.5e %.5e\n", t, system[0], system[1], system[2], system[3], system[4], system[5]);
      }
      gsl_odeiv2_driver_free(drv);
   }
}

int lorentzODE (double t, const double s[], double f[], void *params){
  (void)(t); /* avoid unused parameter warning */
  double *lparams = (double *)params;

  double q  = lparams[0];
  double m  = lparams[1];
  double mu = q/m;

  double Bx = lparams[2];
  double By = lparams[3];
  double Bz = lparams[4];

  double Ex = lparams[5];
  double Ey = lparams[6];
  double Ez = lparams[7];

  f[0] = s[3];
  f[1] = s[4];
  f[2] = s[5];
  f[3] = mu*(Bz*s[4] - By*s[5] + Ex);
  f[4] = mu*(Bx*s[5] - Bz*s[3] + Ey);
  f[5] = mu*(By*s[3] - Bx*s[4] + Ez);
  return GSL_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I don’t use gsl, but you appear to be (trying to) free something on every pass through your i loop, whereas you only allocate it once (before the i loop starts).

Comment: Dear @lastchance, thanks for the help. I have tried putting gsl_odeiv2_driver_free(drv) outside the loop, but the same problem persists. I tried allocating it as well inside the loop, but same problem.

Comment: Where exactly is `t` initialized? Did you compile with `-Wall`?

Comment: Dear @LutzLehmann, thanks a lot for the input. The variable T was indeed not initialized, and then I tried different alternatives. Looks like it works flawlessly if I do the allocation of drv and t inside the first loop. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved :) There were two reasons for why it wasn't working:

- I haven't actually initialized the variable `t`. Corrected by initializing it inside the first loop;
- The allocation of the variable `drv` has to be performed inside the loop as well.

Thanks Lutz Lehmann for pointing it out. The below is the working code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_errno.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_vector.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_odeiv2.h>

using namespace std;

int lorentzODE (double t, const double s[], double f[], void *params);

int main(){

    int noPrimaries = 10;
    double q = 1.0;                           // Particle charge
    double m = 1.0;                           // Particle mass
    double B[3] = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0};            // Magnetic field
    double E[3] = {0.1, 0.0, 0.5};            // Electric field

    double x0[3];                             // Initial position
    double v0[3];                             // Initial velocity

    const gsl_rng_type * T = gsl_rng_ranlxs0;
    gsl_rng * r = gsl_rng_alloc(T);
    gsl_rng_set(r, (unsigned long) time(NULL));

    double t0 = 0.0;
    double tf = 10.0;
    double dt = 0.5;

    double system[6];                  // Initial state vector
    int status;                       // status of driver function
    double paramsB[8];
    paramsB[0] = q;
    paramsB[1] = m;
    paramsB[2] = B[0];
    paramsB[3] = B[1];
    paramsB[4] = B[2];
    paramsB[5] = E[0];
    paramsB[6] = E[1];
    paramsB[7] = E[2];

    const double h = 1.0e-06;
    const double epsAbs = 1.0e-08;
    const double epsRel = 1.0e-10;

    double t, t_next;
    gsl_odeiv2_system odeSystem;
    odeSystem.function = lorentzODE;
    odeSystem.dimension = 6;
    odeSystem.params = paramsB;

    gsl_odeiv2_driver *drv;

    for(int i=0;i<noPrimaries;i++){
    
        t = t0;
        drv = gsl_odeiv2_driver_alloc_y_new(&odeSystem, gsl_odeiv2_step_rk8pd, h, epsAbs, epsRel);

        x0[0] = gsl_rng_uniform (r);
        x0[1] = gsl_rng_uniform (r);
        x0[2] = gsl_rng_uniform (r);
        v0[0] = gsl_rng_uniform (r);
        v0[1] = gsl_rng_uniform (r);
        v0[2] = gsl_rng_uniform (r);
        system[0] = x0[0]; system[1] = x0[1]; system[2] = x0[2];
        system[3] = v0[0]; system[4] = v0[1]; system[5] = v0[2];

        for(t_next = t0+dt; t_next<tf; t_next += dt){

            status = gsl_odeiv2_driver_apply(drv, &t, t_next, system);
            if(status != GSL_SUCCESS){
                printf("Error: status = %d\n", status);
                break;
            }
            printf("%.5e %.5e %.5e %.5e %.5e %.5e %.5e\n", t, system[0], system[1], system[2], system[3], system[4], system[5]);
        }
        gsl_odeiv2_driver_free(drv);
    }
}

int lorentzODE (double t, const double s[], double f[], void *params){
    (void)(t); /* avoid unused parameter warning */
    double *lparams = (double *)params;

    double q  = lparams[0];
    double m  = lparams[1];
    double mu = q/m;

    double Bx = lparams[2];
    double By = lparams[3];
    double Bz = lparams[4];

    double Ex = lparams[5];
    double Ey = lparams[6];
    double Ez = lparams[7];

    f[0] = s[3];
    f[1] = s[4];
    f[2] = s[5];
    f[3] = mu*(Bz*s[4] - By*s[5] + Ex);
    f[4] = mu*(Bx*s[5] - Bz*s[3] + Ey);
    f[5] = mu*(By*s[3] - Bx*s[4] + Ez);
    return GSL_SUCCESS;
}
```